# Finding the smallest subgraph of a given chromatic number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

If I have a graph whose chromatic number I know to be say, 5, is there a method then for finding the smallest subgraph of chromatic number 4? Here is an example where the graph has a chromatic number of 4 and I want to find the smallest subgraph of chromatic number 3:

[image: Moser spindle] Here I have the moser spindle whose chromatic number is 4, and the smallest subgraph with chromatic number 3 would be the complete graph $K_3$:

[image: K3]

I suppose the question can be generalized as: Given a graph with a chromatic number $k$, can one find the smallest subgraph with chromatic number $k-1$? Or is this something that would have to be brute-forced? Is there any optimization that could be made knowing the chromatic number of the super-graph?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it true that every graph with chromatic number $k$ has a subgraph with chromatic number $k-1$?

Comment: @SteveKass that's true, I suppose that there does not necessarily need to be a subgraph with chromatic number k - 1. That being said, would that mean the procedure for finding this subgraph would then just greatly differ between graphs? (If there were a subgraph of chromatic number k - 1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm not an expert, but my sense is that problems like this are often very hard - not that that should stop you from exploring. Hopefully someone else will have ideas.

Comment: @SteveKass No worries, I appreciate your response. I have the same feeling as you, but I'm going to keep looking into it

Comment: Regarding the question in the comments: a graph with chromatic number $k$ must always have subgraphs with every chromatic number $1, 2, \dots, k-1$ as well. Just keep taking away vertices one at a time. Each removed vertex can decrease the chromatic number by at most $1$ (if we can color $G-v$ with $i$ colors, then we can give $v$ a new color and color $G$ with $i+1$ colors), and when we've taken away all but one vertex, we get chromatic number $1$ - so we must have passed through every intermediate chromatic number.

Comment: There is probably no known characterization of graphs with a given chromatic number (except for the first few positive integers) even if you restrict to color-critical graphs on $N$ vertices with chromatic number $k$. On one hand, you can have a color-critical graph with $N=k$, whose smallest $k-1$ critical subgraph is of size just $N-1$. On the other hand, you can have a $k$-color-critical graph on $N$ vertices with $N>>k$, which has a huge independent set (size $N-o(N)$). Therefore the smallest $k$-critical subgraph is of size $o(N)$.

Comment: You are looking for a minimum $k$-vertex-critical subgraph $H$ of a given graph $G$ with chromatic number $\chi(G)=k$. Removing any vertex from $H$ would then result in a minimum $(k-1)$-chromatic subgraph of $G$. For your first question: Can we find the smallest such subgraph? Yes. Can this be efficiently done (no brute forcing involved)? Probably not, since such algorithms need to solve the $k$-graph-colouring problem which is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete.

Comment: There is a well written paper about this subject "Desrosiers, Christian, Philippe Galinier, and Alain Hertz. "Efficient algorithms for finding critical subgraphs." Discrete Applied Mathematics 156.2 (2008): 244-266.". There are some algorithms or heuristics which only work on graphs defined in terms of certain forbidden induced subgraphs, known as $H$-free graphs, which could be of interest as well. For general graphs, I personally do not know any efficient algorithms and there is a high chance that there are none.

Comment: @DavidScholz, your first comment is incorrect. Let $G$ be an odd cycle of length at least 5 and $k=3$. Then $G$ itself is a minimum vertex-critical subgraph of chromatic number 3, but the smallest 2-partite induced subgraph isn't $G$ minus a vertex; it's an edge.

Comment: @Aravind This is very true! Presumably, the "search direction" for the problem would still be correct. Find the smallest minimum vertex-critical subgraph, remove one vertex (resulting in chromatic number $k-1$) and then remove vertices until the chromatic number changes again ($k-2$) and put the last removed vertex back in. Could that work? Of course we can not stop after we have found one such graph, we need to check all subgraphs. Not very satisfying...